# Bootstrap form input control not changing background and border color

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I'm changing the colors of the input control by doing:

```
//Override bootstrap variables
$input-bg: $background-color;
$input-color: yellow;
$input-border-color: $gray-500;
$input-focus-border-color: $primary;
$input-placeholder-color: $gray-600;

//Set background
.form-control
.form-control:active,
.form-control:focus,
.form-control:focus:active {
  background-color: $input-bg;
}
```

But as you can see in the image below, when the form is display with pre-filled controls, the background is a different color. Also, when I start typing in the input control, the text color is gray, but when I leave the control it's yellow.

What am I missing when setting the background and text colors?

[image: Input control]

Comment: Is the prefill being done by your browser?

Comment: @asportnoy yes it is.

Comment: You might want to try with `:autofill` or `:-webkit-autofill`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the chrome autocomplete input background

```css
/* Change the white to any color */
       input:-webkit-autofill,
       input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
       input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
       input:-webkit-autofill:active{
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
       }
```

And for typing in the same font color, you should use :active and :focus with the concerned input field.

Answer (score 0):

once try with "!important"

```html
.form-control
.form-control:active,
.form-control:focus,
.form-control:focus:active {
  background-color: $input-bg!important;
}
```

Comment: I answered with this earlier and OP said it didn't work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing a comma.
It should be:

```
//Set background
.form-control,
```